# How can I create a timer?

Tags: python, timer

I want to know how long it takes since I execute the code to start the timer and then the one to finish. For example, this is something I'd be looking for:

```
import timerlib
import urllib2

timer = timerlib.timer()

print 'Starting download now!'
timer.start()

urllib2.urlopen('http://some.site.com/100mb')

timer.stop()
print 'Downloaded 100mb in ' + str(timer.collectedtime()) + '!'
```

And it would output something like: `Downloaded 100mb in 5m31s!`

How can I do this?

Comment: If you want measurements suitable for profiling, use `timeit` (http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html).

Comment: If you want something easier to integrate into your code, but not as reliable, you should build it yourself around `time.time` or `time.clock` (as appropriate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just printing out a time for the convenience of the end user, not for profiling purposes, you don't need anything fancy; [`time.time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time) returns timestamps you can do arithmetic on and print (in fact, just floating-point seconds):

```
import time
t0 = time.time()
print 'Starting download now!'
urllib2.urlopen('http://some.site.com/100mb')
t = time.time()
print 'Downloaded 100mb in ' + str(t - t0) + '!'
```

But if you're looking for profiling, you definitely want to use [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html):

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit("urllib2.urlopen('http://some.site.com/100mb')", 
              setup="import urllib2", 
              number=1)
```

As you can see, this is not nearly as clean and simple, or as flexible. But the `timeit` library takes care of all kinds of details that novices never think of, and experienced developers still get wrong.

(Of course in real life, you never want to profile anything based on just one run, so you shouldn't be passing `number=1`. That was just to demonstrate the closest equivalent.)

Comment: If I use `timeit`, what if I have multiple tasks to do during the timing period (eg. downloading multiple files, printing stuff)?

Comment: In that case, you can use a multi-line `'''`string, or wrap the whole thing up in a function that takes no args and pass that, but it may be simplest to just turn it into a runnable script and use `python -m timeit` on it from the command line.